# Understanding why theses opcodes from different codes are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, opcode, duck-typing

I would like to deeply understand why these two following generated opcodes are the same (except for the values loaded/stored).

Especially how can this 'BINARY_MULTIPLY' be used for both str and int ?
Does C (CPython) type checks under the hood and apply the correct function whether values are strings or ints ?

And can we say that this mechanism is related to duck typing ?

```
>>> def tata():
...     a = 1
...     b = 1
...     c = a * b
... 
>>> dis.dis(tata)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  4          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             18 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             19 STORE_FAST               2 (c)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE      

>>> def toto():
...     a = "1"
...     b = "1"
...     c = a * b
... 
>>> dis.dis(toto)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('1')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('1')
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  4          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             18 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             19 STORE_FAST               2 (c)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python bytecode is extremely high level, and given the extremely dynamic semantics of the language it cannot do much differently. `BINARY_MULTIPLY` is emitted when you specify `*` in your source code, whatever the types of the operands. What to do exactly is determined at runtime.

This is quite obvious in hindsight: in Python *in general* the types are known only at runtime, and given the flexibility it allows (through e.g. monkeypatching) you can determine what to do only at the very moment of execution. Unsurprisingly, this is one of the reasons why CPython is so slow.

In specific cases, such as these shown in your example, the compiler could perform type inference and perform the calculations at compile time, or at least emit some (imaginary) more specific opcodes. Unfortunately, that would complicate the interpreter and wouldn't help much in the general case, as generally your computations involve parameters coming from the outside, such as:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x
```

`x` here could be of any type, so compile-time smartness isn't useful.

```
def times5(x):
    return x * 5
```

even if 5 here is known, `times5` will do completely different stuff depending from the type of `x` (`"a"` -> `"aaaaa"`; `2` -> `10`; `4.5` -> `22.5`; some custom class type -> it depends from operator overloading, known only at runtime).

You could go the asm.js way and find oblique ways to provide type hints, but instead the high-performance implementation of Python (PyPy) just uses a tracing JIT approach to deduce by itself the parameter types that are commonly used (after running the code for a while) and generates optimized machine code taylored for the observed cases.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is yes. Python (CPython implementation) checks the type of the operands internally and apply the correct function whether values are strings or integers. The reason for this behavior, although is implementation-related but is generally because it's more optimized (C is obviously faster than Python) and in some senses neater to postpone the type checking after determining the operation. One reason for this could be because 1) number of operands are mostly more than operations. 2) type checking (at least in CPython implementation) can be done easily and correctly in an internal process.

The answer to your second question is no because we don't determine the type of those objects based on some other property of the code/equation/etc. we're just doing it with a lower priority.

Also note that another important point regard the order of bytecodes  in equations is that the order of executing the bytecodes is related to the final parsed tree, created by the respective parser. Consider the following example:

```
In [4]: dis.dis("a, b, c, d = 4, 5, 7, 0; a + b * c - d")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               5 ((4, 5, 7, 0))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          4
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             12 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             15 STORE_NAME               3 (d)
             18 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             21 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             24 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             27 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             28 BINARY_ADD
             29 LOAD_NAME                3 (d)
             32 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             33 POP_TOP
             34 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             37 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed related to duck typing which delays type checking or method-validity/existence checking to immediately before the call. The python BINARY_MULTIPLY does exactly what python expression `lambda x, y: x * y` does. It is not explicitly related to any type, as long as the `__mul__` protocol is supported.

If you wonder about how this works in C at all, python delegates the opcode to `PyNumber_Multiply`, which fetches the method from the `__mul__` slot if possible (or it falls back to repeating if the object is a `sequence`), where this method is type specific. In other words the `__mul__`s for int, float, str, list are potentially different.