# Profiling Python code one x86 instruction at a time

Tags: python, profiling

I recently had a discussion about what the Python interpreter is actually doing when you multiply an array with an integer, e.g. `[1] * 3`. Someone suggested that Python will generate 3 copies of `[1]` in memory and then concatenate those copies. A more efficient solution would be a list comprehension (e.g. `[1 for _ in range(3)]`), which would avoid all this overhead.

That sounds pretty logical, but then I decided to compare the runtime of both methods

```py
>>> timeit.timeit('[1] * 1000000', number=100)
0.6567943999999954
>>> timeit.timeit('[1 for _ in range(1000000)]', number=100)
6.787221699999975
```

(Python 3.9.7 on Windows)

Looks like the array multiplication method is an order of magnitude faster than the list comprehension.

I wanted to understand what's going on under the hood, so I tried to disassemble the function:

```py
>>> def array_multiply():
...     return [1] * 3
...
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(array_multiply)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 BUILD_LIST               1
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Well, that wasn't helpful. It just says `BINARY_MULTIPLY`, but not what's happening when you multiply a list and an integer.

Is there a way to go one level deeper? See the C code that handles `[1] * 3`, or inspect the machine code Python is producing when I execute this function?

Comment: I suspect there's a chance what actually happens depends on your interpreter and they can vary. The BINARY_MULTIPLY just means it saw a star (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891921/understanding-why-theses-opcodes-from-different-codes-are-the-same)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the generated c code from cython code that will give you an idea of whats happening:

Cython:

```
x = [1]*3
```

Generated C code:

```
  __pyx_t_1 = PyList_New(1 * 3); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 2, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  { Py_ssize_t __pyx_temp;
    for (__pyx_temp=0; __pyx_temp < 3; __pyx_temp++) {
      __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_int_1);
      __Pyx_GIVEREF(__pyx_int_1);
      PyList_SET_ITEM(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_temp, __pyx_int_1);
    }
  }
  if (PyDict_SetItem(__pyx_d, __pyx_n_s_x, __pyx_t_1) < 0) __PYX_ERR(0, 2, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
```

Seems like it:

1. Make a new PyList object with length of N_elements in list to copy (1) * how many copies (3)
2. Loop over the number of times to copy the list
3. Loop over the items in the list to copy
4. Set the value of the item in the new list with the value in the old list

**Edit:**

To do this yourself, install cython and make a jupyter notebook. On the first cell, run:

```
%load_ext cython
```

On the next cell, run:

```
%%cython -a

x = [1]*3
```

Comment: thanks! how did you get the generated C code? Also, since that's Cython, can we get the same thing for CPython?

Comment: @klamann I edited my answer to say how to run it yourself